# VSTS Adding Users from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

When attempting to add users to VSTS who exist in the connected Azure Active Directory, I am getting a message stating "You are inviting users from outside your directory".  I have checked the setting page and it shows that VSTS is backed by the correct Azure Active Directory.  Why would the users in AAD not come up as available users in VSTS?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean that adding members to one Project ? Also, can you specify what `connected Azure Active Directory` means?

Comment: No, adding members to the entire instance of VSTS (so that they can be added to any project in the instance).  When looking at the VSTS settings page (https://<company name>.visualstudio.com/_admin/_home/settings) it says "This account is backed by the <Company name> Azure Active Directory."

Comment: Can it reflect the user when trying the mail address in Users input box of Add new user window?

Comment: Is the domain part of their username a validated domain in the Azure Active Directory? Try and see if the users' ``@yourcompany.onmicrosoft.com`` usernames work without the warning. If they do, then the AAD is probably missing the domain that you are using when adding the users.

Comment: @user3329073 What's the result now?

Comment: Had to open a ticket with Microsoft - there was an issue with the domain name so VSTS was not able to pull the users from AAD.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to open a ticket with Microsoft to address this issue - even though VSTS was showing that it was linked to the correct AAD, we recently changed our domain for AAD and there are additional changes that MS has to make to ensure the linking is functional.